# second page does not fetch correct data in C#

Tags: asp.net, gridview

First page :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var firstCell = e.Row.Cells[0];
            firstCell.Controls.Clear();
            firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = "ser_job_status1.aspx?Complaint_No = " + firstCell.Text, Text = firstCell.Text, Target = "_blank" });
            Session["Complaint_No"] = firstCell.Text;
        }

    }
```

Second page :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strComplaintNo = Convert.ToString(Session["Complaint_No"]);
        TextBox51.Text = strComplaintNo;
}
```

TextBox.51.Text of my second page fetches value from First page session.
My problem is my textbox51.text fetches value of Complaint_No which is bound finally to gridview rather fetching my hyperlinked value..
Kindly help to solve this issue..

Comment: question makes no sense.

Comment: debug and check the value of firstCell.Text when you are asigning it to session. How are you navigating to second page?

Comment: ya i did Apurv Gupta... the value of firstcell.Text is the value which is finally bound to the gridview. since i am calling GridView1.DataBind(); after RowdataBound event gets completed the value of firstcell.Text is the value which is bound at last.. i think u can understand ..can u pls giv me a solution to fetch the hyperlinked value..

Answer (score 0):

`Session["Complaint_No"] = firstCell.Text;` is set in your session, so value of `firstCell.Text` must be fetched in the second page.

Comment: ya i understood... how to change the code so that it fetches hyperlinked value... Awaiting ur reply Saurabh

Comment: can u post here, what u wana to fetch in second page.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Session["Complaint_No"] = firstCell.Text;
```

to

```
Session["Complaint_No"] = ((HyperLink)firstCell.Controls[0]).NavigateUrl;
```

Comment: I think this is because ia am calling  GridView1.DataBind(); after Rowdatabound events gets completed.. so it fetches last value which is bound to gridview and the same is passed to second page...am i right

Comment: I guess not, it's because you are assigning the same text to the  new control (Text = firstCell.Text in your hyperlink);

Comment: in `firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = "ser_job_status1.aspx?Complaint_No = " + firstCell.Text, Text = firstCell.Text, Target = "_blank" });` change Text=firstCell.Text to Text="new text" and see what you get on second page.

Comment: why don't you simply put it like? `"Session["complaint_link"]=ser_job_status1.aspx?Complaint_No = " + firstCell.Text`